# How to read a list of objects from a file in Dart/Flutter

Tags: file, flutter, dart

I am developing a Flutter App, and I wish to save a list of objects (Contacts) to the app directory.
As suggested in the Cookbook, I use the path_provider package and the File class of Dart.

Getting to write the objects was easy (I think - I didn't get any error). Here is the code I used for writing the list:

```
Future<void> writeContact(List<Contact> contacts) async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File('${directory.path}/contacts.txt');

    // Write the file
    IOSink sink =  file.openWrite(mode: FileMode.write);
    sink.write(contacts);
    sink.close();
}
```

The question is - how to I read this file and populate the List of Contacts?

Thanks, Gal.

Comment: How IOSink writes the file? As binary or json?

Comment: The sink is used for writing the object - I didn't convert it to json, so I am guessing it is writing this as Binary. The question is, how do I read it back and parse it properly into the List of objects. In this case Contacts

Comment: Guessing does not help, you need to make you question more clear and your code too

Comment: You are right. Never the less, my question remains, what is the method for Write and Read a List of Objects to and from a File in Dart? Thanks, Gal.